# Lodash and AngularJS ngResource promise don't work well

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, lodash, ngresource

I use lodash within my AngularJs app and it works well for local collections/arrays.

When I try to use it like so it doesn't work:

```
vm.colorsSizes = _.uniq(commonData.stock, 'colorName');
```

where `commonData.stock` is an array that resolves from an ngResource call.

```
angular
    .module("common.services")
    .factory("commonData",
            ["stockResource",
             commonData]);

function commonData(stockResource) {

    return {
        stock: stockResource.query()
    }
}
```

Why this happens and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is it resolved when you execute this line?

Comment: If I call it like `vm.stock = commonData.stock;` it gets resolved but not in lodash `_.uniq()` call.

Comment: `commonData.stock` must be returning promise. You need to resolve it first

Comment: @Bogac If you do that, it gets resolved _eventually_, because you are just assigning `commonData.stock` from one place to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to access it when it hasn't resolved yet and it's still empty. Give this a whirl:

```
commonData.stock.$promise.then(function () {
    vm.colorSizes = _.uniq(commonData.stock, 'colorName');
});
```